# AWS Client S3 mv command is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using aws cli to move the files around in S3 in the same bucket. As far as I know, AWS S3 does not maintain the folder structure. It stores the entire path as key to the file and displays it in folder structure in console.

Now my question is if I want move the file, it is basically renaming the file key. However, the following command will show transfer.

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket1/stage1/part1/$i/stage1.prime s3://bucket1/stage1/$i/part1/stage1.prime
```

The terminal will output

```
Completed 2.1 GiB/4.2 GiB (86.4 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
```

Comment: Technically, renaming ("moving") an object actually copies the object to the new key then deletes the old object, but the copy action should be internal to S3.  Can you use `--debug` and capture the requests being sent?  If you see `x-amz-copy-source-range` headers, the cli may just be doing an internal-to-s3 multipart copy, and just reporting the status of those internal copy actions for progress reporting purposes.  I believe `aws s3 mv ... --debug 2> >(tee somelogfilename.txt >&2)` should capture that debug to a file for easier review.